# Stream decoding of Base64 data

Tags: java, hadoop, base64, gzipinputstream

I have some large base64 encoded data (stored in snappy files in the hadoop filesystem).
This data was originally gzipped text data.
I need to be able to read chunks of this encoded data, decode it, and then flush it to a GZIPOutputStream.

Any ideas on how I could do this instead of loading the whole base64 data into an array and calling Base64.decodeBase64(byte[]) ?

Am I right if I read the characters till the '\r\n' delimiter and decode it line by line?
e.g. :

```
for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
    if (byteData[i] == CARRIAGE_RETURN || byteData[i] == NEWLINE) {
       if (i < byteData.length - 1 && byteData[i + 1] == NEWLINE)
            i += 2;
       else 
            i += 1;

       byteBuffer.put(Base64.decodeBase64(record));

       byteCounter = 0;
       record = new byte[8192];
    } else {
        record[byteCounter++] = byteData[i];
    }
}
```

Sadly, this approach doesn't give any human readable output.
Ideally, I would like to stream read, decode, and stream out the data.

Right now, I'm trying to put in an inputstream and then copy to a gzipout

```
byteBuffer.get(bufferBytes);

InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bufferBytes);
inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream , gzipOutputStream);
```

And it gives me a 
java.io.IOException: Corrupt GZIP trailer

Comment: `byteBuffer.put(Base64.decodeBase64(record));`

Shouldn't that be `byteBuffer.put(Base64.encodeBase64(record));`

Comment: The 'record' is Base64 encoded. I'm trying to get the decoded data and add it to the ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go step by step:

1. You need a `GZIPInputStream` to read zipped data (that and not a `GZIPOutputStream`; the output stream is used to compress data). Having this stream you will be able to read the uncompressed, original binary data. This requires an `InputStream` in the constructor.
2. You need an input stream capable of reading the Base64 encoded data. I suggest the handy [`Base64InputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html) from [apache-commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/). With the constructor you can set the line length, the line separator and set `doEncode=false` to decode data. This in turn requires another input stream - the raw, Base64 encoded data.
3. This stream depends on how you get your data; ideally the data should be available as `InputStream` - problem solved. If not, you may have to use the `ByteArrayInputStream` (if binary), `StringBufferInputStream` (if string) etc.

Roughly this logic is:

```
InputStream fromHadoop = ...;                                  // 3rd paragraph
Base64InputStream b64is =                                      // 2nd paragraph
    new Base64InputStream(fromHadoop, false, 80, "\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
GZIPInputStream zis = new GZIPInputStream(b64is);              // 1st paragraph
```

Please pay attention to the arguments of `Base64InputStream` (line length and end-of-line byte array), you may need to tweak them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nikos. The Base64InputStream class helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nikos for pointing me in the right direction.
Specifically this is what I did:

```
private static final byte NEWLINE = (byte) '\n';
private static final byte CARRIAGE_RETURN = (byte) '\r';

byte[] lineSeparators = new byte[] {CARRIAGE_RETURN, NEWLINE};      
Base64InputStream b64is = new Base64InputStream(inputStream, false, 76, lineSeparators);

GZIPInputStream zis = new GZIPInputStream(b64is);
```

Isn't 76 the length of the Base64 line? I didn't try with 80, though.

Comment: If it was fixed at 76 length, then they wouldn't've included the constructor argument. Also think about data URIs where the whole thing is one line.