# Android how to download zip file using soap liabrary

Tags: java, android, soap

I want to download zip file from server by using ksoap liabry.I am getting data in base64 please give solution that how to convert base64 and save it as zip file

Comment: You should read do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980307/stream-decoding-of-base64-data , to convert a file stream to Base64 File. Anyway provide more detail and some example code in order to help you easier

Answer (score 0):

```
                byte[] bytes;
                byte[] data = result.getBytes("UTF-8");
                File outputFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath(), + "filename.zip");
                new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                bytes = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                File filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder/" + "filename.zip");
                OutputStream pdffos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
                pdffos.write(bytes);
                pdffos.flush();
                pdffos.close();
```

Answer (score -2):

This Code help me to downlad apk and store to sd card.
This may help you also..

```
public class SaveInBackground extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {
    View v;
    OutputValue ov;
    Boolean isError= false;

    public SaveInBackground(View v,OutputValue ov){
        this.v = v;
        this.ov = ov;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        Message.setText("Downloading...");
        isToLoop =true;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (isToLoop) {
                    SystemClock.sleep(500);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int count = bar.getProgress() + 1;
                            bar.setProgress(count);
                        }
                    });
                    if(isToLoop)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        bar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Globle.Infosoft_serverLink.replace("/Service.asmx/","")+ov.url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                isError = true;
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            //publishProgress(80);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+ov.Name+".apk";
            output = new FileOutputStream(path );

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            return path;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            isError =true;
            Snackbar.make(v,"Error while accessing storage.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if(!isError) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(result)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        Message.setText("Downloaded");
        reset(v);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a question